# How to run multiple execute windows batch in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, appium

I am trying to open appium, avd, and ride to run a test in Jeninks. I have the following in execute windows batch command:

```
C:
cd C:\Users\Gebruiker
appium
adb start-server
cd C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator
emulator -avd Pixel_3_API_23
ride.py
D:
cd D:\RIDE - testproject\Avans-One
robot -d Open_settings_connect_wifi AvansOne
```

It keeps loading after opening Appium, the first step. I have tried seperating the steps but it still doesnt work. It completes the first step and then just keeps loading. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, this is happening because the command used to start the app is not returning while the app is running. So you will have to use a command that allows you to run the application in the background.

Check with something like below.

```
START /B title program
```

e.g.:

```
 C:
 cd C:\Users\Gebruiker
 START /B "" appium
```

You can read more about the background process [here](https://superuser.com/questions/198525/how-can-i-execute-a-windows-command-line-in-background)